# Strong approximation, Chinese remainder theorem and surjectivity of reduction

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am trying to make sense of different interpretations of the strong approximation and related properties in algebraic groups. Already in the classical case, say for $SL(2)$, I would like to understand why are the (two last) following statements equivalents

- the natural embedding $SL(2, \mathbb{Q}) \to SL(2,\mathbb{A}^S)$ is dense, for any nonempty set of places $S$
- the natural embedding $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}) \to SL(2, \widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ has dense image (for the product of the topology naturally inherited from the $p$-adic one on the right)
- the reduction $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}) \to SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/m)$ is surjective, for all $m > 0$

This is the strong approximation property.

Do we have the same dictionary (between a topological property and a reduction map property) for the weak approximation (i.e. when only $G(\mathbb{Q}) \to G(\mathbb{A}_S)$ is dense)?

Does this have a relation with the Hensel lemma, stating that $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}_p) \to SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ is surjectrive?